# Unknown hardware filter/amplifier in setup

Tags: measurement, setup

I found the following picture on the internet. To be honest, it was the first time I saw such a (filter/amplifier?) plugged in an oscilloscope. Anyone knows which device it is?
 Thanks in advance ;)

[image]

Comment: Please provide the link to the original web page which includes that photo. There could be useful context / background information on that page.

Comment: As Sam says, without context, it could be anything.  A flux capacitor isolator.

Comment: looks like a HAM filter; those guys make that stuff all the time...

Comment: That mechanical construction is a neat way of lashing up any 'mid frequency' (high enough to want good grounding continuity but not so high as to need full coax or ground plane) widget. Add components of your choice between the terminals of the BNCs. Could be a single isolating resistor, low, high or bandpass filter, bias injection Tee, your imagination is your limit. Note that we know it's hot a 'high' frequency from the use of the coax Tee!

Comment: @SamGibson you can find the full picture in this [document](https://www.brightsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Brightsight-Newsletter-March-2016.pdf), apparently a fault injection setup ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks homemade. Could be whatever the guy who made it wanted it to be. Likely possibilities are

- Attenuator, to allow connecting a higher power signal than the 'scope is able to handle.
- Low-pass filter to filter out noise.
- High-pass filter to cut out a high DC bias.
- Arbitrary other filter that meets the needs of the particular measurement.
- Envelope detector to allow measuring the message signal of an AM RF signal.